# Is it possible to set Twilio Verify api token expiry time?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api, verify, totp

I want to use Twilio's "Verify" service for my 4 digits OTP verification, but I don't see any expiry time mentioned in there api documents. I can't use there "Authy" service since my requirement is to have 4 digits OTP. Is it possible to set expiry time in Verify api or is there any standard time?

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are valid for a default period of 10 minutes once generated. You can customize the validity period of your Service's tokens to any value between 2 minutes and 24 hours by [contacting Support](https://www.twilio.com/console/support/tickets/create).

More details: [Twillio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/rate-limits-and-timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard time of 10 minutes, reference the documentation below.

> [Twilio Verify Best Practices](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/developer-best-practices#token-validity-period)

Comment: it's possible to reduce that time?

Comment: No, it is 10 minutes. Why?